# System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks, dotnet-httpclient, .net-4.8

I have an application that make a lot of requests to external web API.
In the same run, the requests number can be more than 2000 (the API response is paginated).

I don't understand why at a random (high, usually around 1000, but one time also at 200) number of request, I receive the error below.

I tried to dispose and reinitialize the http client every 20 request, but nothing changed.
Furthermore, I also tried to increase the Timeout to 5 hours.

```cs
public static void InitializeClient()
{
    var handler = new WinHttpHandler(); //used to allow body with GET in .NET Framework
    myHttpClient = new HttpClient(handler);
    myHttpClient.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromHours(5);
    myHttpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(Config.APIUrl);
    myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json") { CharSet = Encoding.UTF8.WebName });
    myHttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Token", Config.AuthToken);
}
```

The method throwing the exception (called by xunit testing):

```
public async void GetCustomers_ShouldWork()
{
    HTTPClient.InitializeClient();

    var ex = await Record.ExceptionAsync(() => HTTPClient.GetCustomers());

    Assert.Null(ex);
}
```

```
public static async Task<List<ModelCustomers>> GetCustomers()
{          
    try
    {
        int contPageRequestSameClient = 0;
        int maxPageRequestSameClient = 20;

        List<ModelCustomers> modelCustomers = new List<ModelCustomers>();

        DateTime entityDateLastImportSuccess = DBClient.ReadEntityDateLastImportSuccess(Config.Entities.Customer.ToString());

        List<string> requestFields = new List<string> /*{ "number", "id" }*/{ };

        int requestPage = 1;
        bool hasNextPage = true;

        while (hasNextPage)
        {
            SyncLogger.RegisterLog($"Request page: {requestPage}");

            var getRequestBody = new ModelCustomersRequestBody
            {
                page = requestPage,
                fields = requestFields,
                q = new ModelCustomersRequestBodyFilter { updated_at_gt = entityDateLastImportSuccess.ToString() }
            };

            string jsonGetRequestBody = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(getRequestBody);

            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage
            {
                Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                RequestUri = new Uri(myHttpClient.BaseAddress + "customers"),
                Content = new StringContent(jsonGetRequestBody, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")
            };

            HttpResponseMessage response = await myHttpClient.SendAsync(request);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                try
                {
                    ModelCustomers responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelCustomers>();

                    modelCustomers.Add(responseData);

                    int? nextPage = responseData.info.pagination.nextPage;

                    hasNextPage = nextPage.HasValue;

                    if (hasNextPage)
                    {
                        requestPage++;
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    string responseString;
                    responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    SyncLogger.RegisterLog($"Json in error: { responseString } ");
                    throw;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                SyncLogger.RegisterLog($"Response: {response.ReasonPhrase + response.ToString()}");

                throw new Exception("HTTP response not IsSuccessStatusCode");
            }

            contPageRequestSameClient++;

            if (contPageRequestSameClient == maxPageRequestSameClient)
            {
                //reset client
                myHttpClient.Dispose();
                InitializeClient();
                contPageRequestSameClient = 0;
                SyncLogger.RegisterLog($"HTTP Client reset");
            }
        }
        return modelCustomers;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //SyncLogger.RegisterLog(ex.ToString());
        throw;
    }
}
```

Here is the error stack:

```
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.Http.WinHttpException: Error 12002 calling WINHTTP_CALLBACK_STATUS_REQUEST_ERROR, 'Timeout dell'operazione'.
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.RendezvousAwaitable`1.GetResult()
   at System.Net.Http.WinHttpHandler.<StartRequestAsync>d__122.MoveNext()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
```

.NET Framework 4.8

Comment: Are you using `await` everywhere or do you have a `.Wait` or `.Result` somewhere?

Comment: Yes, the method that make the requests is an `async task`.
The request is sent with `HttpResponseMessage response = await myHttpClient.SendAsync(request);` and the response content is read with `ModelCustomers responseData = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<ModelCustomers>();`

Comment: Please show that code, and please show how you call *that* function

Comment: added in the question

Comment: You are missing `using` on `request` and `response`, also don't create new `HttpClient` each time, just keep one in a static field. Also, maybe the server is just overloaded?

Comment: the `myhttpClient` is a static `HttpClient`, I tried to refresh it every 20 request to avoid the problem. I try to add using on request and response and I'll let you know.

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing above helped to solve. Got the same exception